# Tensorflow for Poets | Relaunching Docker | invalid reference format

Tags: powershell, docker, tensorflow

I'm a beginner, trying out Tensorflow for Poets. I have been following instructions to build my own image classifier. But I get an error while following Step 3 of the tutorial at [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#2)

When I run the following command in PowerShell:

> **docker run -it \   --publish 6006:6006 \   --volume ${HOME}/tf_files:/tf_files \   --workdir /tf_files \
>
>   tensorflow/tensorflow:1.1.0 bash**

I get the following error:

> **C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid reference format. See 'C:\Program
>   Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'**

I have tried passing home address instead of $HOME, tried even lower case for the address. But still I get the same error.

I'd appreciate thoughts and suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: did you solve it ?